# Update MySQL Field in VB.NET Error

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net

I am trying to make a very simple program that connects to a MySQL database using VB.NET.  My program only has one form and one label.  I setup my MySQL database to have a table and one field (a

VARCHAR)called "Tab1".  I manually inserted the value "CLOSED" into the Tab1 field using PHPMyAdmin. I want my program to change the value of the field to OPEN/CLOSED and I also want the label text on my form

to change too when it's clicked.

So far, I've added the MySQL.data reference to my project and added:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

To the General_Declarations

Also I declared a global variable containing a MySQL Connection:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
```

Here is my function that connects to MySQL:

```
Private Function Connect(ByVal server As String, ByRef user As String, ByRef password As String, ByRef database As String)
        ' Connection string with MySQL Info
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=" + server + ";" _
        & "user id=" + user + ";" _
        & "password=" + password + ";" _
        & "database=" + database + ";"
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Return True
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            Return MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
```

I made the program connect to MySQL on Form_Load like this:

```
Connect("db4free.net", "boomun", "*******", "boomdb")
```

And it connects fine but here is where I have the trouble.... I want the field to change from CLOSED to OPEN when I click Label1.  It does change to OPEN on the first click, but I get a mysql Error Msgbox saying "There is already an open DataReader associated with this connection that must be closed first".... How do I close the DataReader?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim myData As MySqlDataReader
        Dim SQL As String

        SQL = "SELECT * FROM `boomtable` WHERE `Tab1` = 'CLOSED'"

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        myCommand.CommandText = SQL
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand

        Try
            myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
            myData.Read()
            If myData.HasRows = 0 Then
                Label1.Text = "CLOSED"
                SQL = "UPDATE boomtable SET Tab1 = 'CLOSED' WHERE Tab1 = 'OPEN'"
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myData.Close()

            Else
                Label1.Text = "OPEN"
                SQL = "UPDATE boomtable SET Tab1 = 'OPEN' WHERE Tab1 = 'CLOSED'"
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myData.Close()

            End If
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

I have `myData.close()` there but I still get that error! What gives?

Here is the entire code of the project all together:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection

    Private Function Connect(ByVal server As String, ByRef user As String, ByRef password As String, ByRef database As String)
        ' Connection string with MySQL Info
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=" + server + ";" _
        & "user id=" + user + ";" _
        & "password=" + password + ";" _
        & "database=" + database + ";"
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Return True
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            Return MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim myData As MySqlDataReader
        Dim SQL As String

        SQL = "SELECT * FROM `boomtable` WHERE `Tab1` = 'CLOSED'"

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        myCommand.CommandText = SQL
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand

        Try
            myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
            myData.Read()
            If myData.HasRows = 0 Then
                Label1.Text = "CLOSED"
                SQL = "UPDATE boomtable SET Tab1 = 'CLOSED' WHERE Tab1 = 'OPEN'"
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myData.Close()

            Else
                Label1.Text = "OPEN"
                SQL = "UPDATE boomtable SET Tab1 = 'OPEN' WHERE Tab1 = 'CLOSED'"
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myData.Close()

            End If
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Connect("db4free.net", "boomun", "boom123", "boomdb")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: A hand full advices for VB.NET: First, you can directly assign values to variables: `Dim myTest As String = "TestString"`. Second, turn `Option Strict/Infer/Explicit On`. Third, dump the ugly `Microsoft.VisualBasic`-VB6-Legacy-Namespace. Fourth, get your calls right, `MySqlDataReader.HasRows` is a `Boolean` property.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Try...Catch`-Block put a `Finally`-

Your trying to reuse a Connection object that is already open.
so you need to close the connection, and then reopen when you rerun the next query.

```
Try

Catch ex as Exception
    'catch Exception'
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try
```

** EDIT MADE **

You need to disconnect after you read the Data and reconnect again to do the Update.

Comment: I don't see what edit you made it looks the same to me?  I tried it and still get the same error.

Comment: This was the Edit "You need to disconnect after you read the Data and reconnect again to do the Update."